# Finding the roots of two polynomials from their sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Problem: given that $a, b, c, d > 0$ and the sum of all real roots of the polynomials
$dx^{865}+cx^{65}+bx^5+a$ and
$ax^{865}+bx^{860}+cx^{800}+d$ is $-4.25$, what are these roots?

So apparently the powers of $x$ under the same coefficient sum up to 865 here. I can also see that polynomial $1$  has only one solution. Can't really think of anything else.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two polynomials? Can you say anything about the relationship between their roots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\alpha$ is a root of the first, then $ \frac{ 1}{ \alpha}$ is a root of the second.

**Hint:** How many real roots are there in the first equation? Use the fact that $ a, b, c, d > 0$.

Hence, conclude that

> $\alpha_1 + \frac{1}{ \alpha_1 } = -4.25$